# Layouts jQuery Isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

We have a problem with the plug-in (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), it works very well.

But I am having a problem with the order of the boxes. I wonder if it could be arranged from left to right. I've illustrate my question in the screen [here](http://clip2net.com/s/1T4B8).

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer** :
To my knowledge, the only possible way to achieve this without code change is to initialize the plugin using :

```
$('#container').isotope({ layoutMode : 'fitColumns' });
```

The plugin use the `layoutMode : 'masonry'` as default value

Comment: fitColumns will arrange them from top to bottom, not left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell from a static image what you really want the layout logic to do; have you looked into [category rows](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/category-rows.html) to achieve a certain order?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no way in isotope to have both the close fitting of the `masonry` layout *and* the preserved order layouts like of `fitRows` or `fitColumns`